# Необходимо ли перед закрывающей скобкой ставить точку?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, — в художественной литературе — после вставной реплики в скобках необходима ли точка?

Он подходит ближе. (Вокруг тишина.) Затем поднимает с пола лист бумаги.

Comment: Или если в скобках будет иная фраза. (Звук раскрывающейся молнии(.))

Comment: @shampar Нет таких понятий **открывающая** или **закрывающая** точка. Таковые есть кавычки или скобки. Думаю, что вопрос должен звучать так: _Необходимо ли перед закрывающей **скобкой** ставить **точку**?_ И — точка ставится _после_ кавычек.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, торопилась и не заметила, что допустила ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно. Если в скобках законченная фраза (а не пояснение предыдущего слова или оборота), то как и для любого предложения, в конце требуется точка.

Однако при записи авторских ремарок в драматических текстах от этого правила часто отступают. Но этот прием в правилах пока не находит отражения.

Comment: Можно убрать запятую после "однако"?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой да.